# PANDAS - converting a column with lists as values to dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I'm working with a dataset of airbnb listings. one of the columns is called amenisities,
and contains all of the amenisities that listing has to offer.
several examples:

```
[Internet, Wifi, Paid parking off premises]

[Internet, Wifi, Kitchen]

[Wifi, Smoking allowed, Heating]
```

I would like to replace this column with several binary column, one for each kind of amenisty.
so one of them, for example, will be:

```
wifi --> 0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1
```

I found a way to achive this with for loops:

```
all_amenities = []
for row in amenities:
    all_amenities += row

all_amenities = set(all_amenities)
for col in all_amenities:
    df[col] = 0

for i,amenities_of_listing in enumerate(amenities):
    for amenity in amenities_of_listing:
        df.loc[i,amenity] = 1
```

but this is taking forever to run - can someone here think of a more afficiant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) what working nice if large `DataFrame`:

```
print (df)
                                   amenisities
0  [Internet, Wifi, Paid parking off premises]
1                    [Internet, Wifi, Kitchen]
2             [Wifi, Smoking allowed, Heating]

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['amenisities']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df1)
   Heating  Internet  Kitchen  Paid parking off premises  Smoking allowed  \
0        0         1        0                          1                0   
1        0         1        1                          0                0   
2        1         0        0                          0                1   

   Wifi  
0     1  
1     1  
2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can also try with [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) or [`series.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
pd.get_dummies(s.explode()).max(level=0)
```

Or:

```
s.str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

replace `s` with `df['column_name']`

---

```
   Heating  Internet  Kitchen  Paid parking off premises  Smoking allowed  \
0        0         1        0                          1                0   
1        0         1        1                          0                0   
2        1         0        0                          0                1   

   Wifi  
0     1  
1     1  
2     1
```